# Evaluating $I(z,s)=\int_0^1\int_0^1\left(1-\frac{(1-x)(1-y)}{(1-(1-z)x)(1-(1-z)y)}\right)^{s-2}\,\mathrm dx\mathrm dy$

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, multivariable-calculus, gamma-function, digamma-function

I came across the following double integral in a statistics problem:

For $z>0$
$$
I(z,s)=\int_0^1\int_0^1\left(1-\frac{(1-x)(1-y)}{(1-(1-z)x)(1-(1-z)y)}\right)^{s-2}\,\mathrm dx\mathrm dy.
$$
All I was interested in was the values of $s$ for which $I$ converges $(s>0)$. That said, the integral looked interesting enough to try and evaluate.  I was successful in evaluating the special case $z=1$ (see below) but could not solve for the general solution. Any ideas on how to solve it?

> **Case for $z=1$:**
>
> We have
> $$
> I(1,s)=\int_0^1\int_0^1\left(1-(1-x)(1-y)\right)^{s-2}\,\mathrm dx\mathrm dy.
> $$
> Substituting $(u,v)=(1-(1-x)(1-y),x)$, the resulting integral in $v$ is easily evaluated in terms of the natural logarithm; hence,
> $$
> I(1,s)=-\int_0^1 u^{s-2}\log(1-u)\,\mathrm du.
> $$
> Observe that $-u^{s-2}\log(1-u)\sim u^{s-1}+\mathcal O(u^s)$ as $u\nearrow 0$, which tells us the integral should converge for $s>0$. Using the series expansion for the logarithm we then integrate termwise to find
> $$
> I(1,s)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{1}{k(k+s-1)}=\frac{H_{s-1}}{s-1},
> $$
> where $H_{s-1}=\psi(s)+\gamma$ is the generalized harmonic number, $\psi(z)=\partial_z\log\Gamma(z)$ is the digamma function and $\gamma=0.577\dots$ is the Euler–Mascheroni constant.

Comment: I think you have a missing parenthesis in the denominator of the integrand -- I'm guessing it should follow the $y$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that $s$ is an integer $\geq 2$, each term in the binomial expansion of the integrand is separable into a product of integrals over $x$ and $y$. Defining $N=s-2$ and $z'=1-z$ for notational simplicity,
$$
I(1-z',N+2) = \int_{0}^1 dx \int_{0}^1 dy \sum_{k=0}^N \binom{N}{k} \left( -\frac{(1-x)(1-y)}{(1-z'x)(1-z'y)}\right)^k \\
= \sum_{k=0}^N \binom{N}{k} (-1)^k \left\{
\left(
    \int_{0}^1 \left( \frac{1-x}{1-z'x}\right)^k \, dx
\right)^2
\right\}
$$
As a check, when $z=1$ and thus $z'=0$, the inner integral is $1/(1+k)$, and so
$$
I(1,N+2) = \sum_{k=0}^N \binom{N}{k} \frac{(-1)^k}{(1+k)^2}
$$
which sums (as verified by Mathematica) to the same result derived by you. For general $z'$, define
$$
\xi(z) =\int_0^1 \left( \frac{1-x}{1-(1-z)x} \right)^k \, dx
$$
Unfortunately I cannot evaluate this integral, but it can be expanded to linear order around $z=1$ to give
$$
\xi(z) = \frac{1}{1+k} + \frac{k}{(k+1)(k+2)} (1-z) + \mathcal{O}((1-z)^2)
$$
yielding (for integral $s \geq 2$ at least) (*edit* and with some corrections to converting the expansion of $\xi(z)$ into that of $\xi^2(z)$)
$$
I(z,s) = \frac{\psi(s)+\gamma}{s-1} + 2 \frac{s(\psi(s+1)+\gamma)-2s+1}{s(s-1)} (1-z) + \mathcal{O}((1-z)^2)
$$

**ADDITION**

As pointed out by the OP, from Mathematica or integral tables (c.f. https://dlmf.nist.gov/15.6#E1) we have
$$
\xi(z) = \int_0^1 \left(\frac{1-x}{1-(1-z)x}\right)^k \, dx = \frac{1}{k+1} F(1,k;k+2;1-z)
$$
(Note that the referenced table represents the identity using the Olver form of the hypergeometric function $\mathbf{F}(a,b;c;z)=F(a,b;c;z)/\Gamma(c)$, and that $F(a,b; c; z)$ is symmetric in $a$ and $b$). This gives the result, for integral $s \geq 2$,
$$
\left. I(z,s)\right|_{s \in \mathbb{N}, s\geq 2} = \sum_{k=0}^{s-2} \binom{s-2}{k} \frac{(-1)^k}{(1+k)^2} F(1,k;k+2,1-z)^2
$$

At least formally, without worrying about convergence, this could be generalized to non-integer $s$ (and $s=0,1$) by extending the series to infinity (with generalized binomial coefficients), but this is probably less useful. The Taylor series of the squared hypergeometric function is
$$
F(1,k;k+2;1-z)^2 = \left( \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(1)_n (k)_n}{(k+2)_n} \frac{(1-z)^n}{n!} \right)^2 \\
= \left( \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{k(k+1)}{(k+n)(k+n+1)} (1-z)^n \right)^2 \\
= \sum_{n=0}^\infty \left\{ \sum_{m=0}^n \frac{k(k+1)}{(k+m)(k+m+1)} \frac{k(k+1)}{(k+n-m)(k+n-m+1)} \right\} (1-z)^n
$$
This inner sum is somewhat messy, but can be broken up with partial fractions to yield
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{2k^2(k+1)^2}{2k+n+1} \left(  \frac{H_{k+n}-H_{k-1}}{2k+n} - \frac{H_{k+n+1}-H_k}{2k+n+2}  \right) (1-z)^n
$$
Substituting into the expression for $I(s,z)$ and exchanging the order of summation, the Taylor series $I(z,s) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty C_n (1-z)^n$ has coefficients
$$
C_n = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \binom{s-2}{k} \frac{2k^2 (-1)^k}{2k+n+1} \left(  \frac{H_{k+n}-H_{k-1}}{2k+n} - \frac{H_{k+n+1}-H_k}{2k+n+2}  \right)
$$
This reduces to the special cases above for $n=0,1$, e.g.
$$
C_0 = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \binom{s-2}{k} \frac{2k^2 (-1)^k}{2k+1} \left(  \frac{1}{2k^2} - \frac{1}{2(k+1)^2}  \right) = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \binom{s-2}{k} \frac{k^2 (-1)^k}{(k+1)^2} \\
C_1 = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \binom{s-2}{k} \frac{2k^2 (-1)^k}{2k+2} \left(  \frac{1}{k(k+1)} - \frac{1}{(k+1)(k+2)}  \right) = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \binom{s-2}{k} \frac{2k (-1)^k}{(k+1)^2(k+2)}
$$
and so on.

Comment: The series formula at the end is magnificent! Nice work.

Comment: Mathematica gives $\xi=F(1,k;2+k;1-z)/(k+1)$ which I suspect can be arrived at from integral representations of the hypergeometric function.

Comment: It is interesting that $H_s=\psi(s+1)+\gamma$ gives the harmonic numbers for $s\in\Bbb N$

Comment: @AaronHendrickson "Mathematica gives..." Ah, interesting; I don't have a Mathematica license and WolframAlpha/Sage timed out on that one. Do you mind if I add that to the answer?

Comment: One important error I just noticed: this series expansion around $z=1$ is not quite right because $\xi(z)$ is squared in the integral, and so this term probably picks up a factor of 2.

Comment: @jwimberley Of course. Add it. https://dlmf.nist.gov/15.6.E1

Comment: @AaronHendrickson After you selected the answer I found a significant error; it's corrected now but the now isn't as "complete."

Comment: @jwimberley see my comments in the "answer" I posted. I do agree that we are not quite at the solution to the problem but are at least close.

Comment: @jwimberley As a matter of fact, the integrand for $z=1$ case probably dominates the integrand for the general case for either $z\in(0,1]$ or $z\in[1,\infty)$. And since the $z=1$ case converges for $s>0$ so will the general case for one of the above specified constraints on $z$. This would justify interchange of series and integral for $s<2$.

Comment: You're saying, $\left|\sum_k \binom{s-2}{k} (\cdots)^k \right| \leq \left| 1-(1-x)(1-y) \right|^{s-2}$?

Comment: @jwimberley See my updated answer/comments. The series you derived should hold for all $s>0$ although it does converge very slowly for $s<2$. Either way, at least the series is a valid solution. Fell free to use all, part, or none of what I wrote in your answer.  It would be great is the series could be evaluated but it looks to be nontrivial.

Comment: @AaronHendrickson Great! I may not add this into my answer, as it's well described in your answer. I also think there's an outside chance the series could be summed, with a lot of tedious effort. Following up on rural reader's answer, I think it can be shown that $F(1,k,k+2,x)/(k(k+1)) = \log(1-x)/x^{k+1} - \log(1-x)/x^k + 1/x^k - \sum_{n=1}^{k-1} z^{-n}/((k-n)(k-n+1))$.

Comment: @jwimberley I agree that there's a possibility it can be evaluated with a few tricks. It turns out your solution holds for all complex-valued $s$ with positive real part which I have reflected in my updated comments.

Answer (score 3):

This is meant to supplement the solution derived by @jwimberley. The solution derived was (after some algebraic manipulations):
$$
I(z,s)=\sum_{k=0}^{s-2}\frac{(2-s)_k}{k!}\frac{F^2(1,k;k+2;1-z)}{(k+1)^2},
$$
which held for $z>0$ and $s\in\Bbb N$ with $s\geq 2$. I would like to show that this solution in fact holds for all $s\in\Bbb C: \Re s>0$. First note that the solution above is equivalent to
$$
I(z,s)=1+\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{(2-s)_k}{(k+1)^2k!}F^2(1,k;k+2;1-z),
$$
since the first term is always one and $s\in\Bbb N\land s\geq 2\implies (2-s)_k=0$ for $k=s-1,s,s+1,\dots$

To show convergence for other values of $s$ we will use the integral representation of the hypergeometric function [(DLMF $15.6.1$)](http://dlmf.nist.gov/15.6.E1) to write
$$
F\left({1,k \atop k+2};1-z\right)=\int_0^1\frac{1}{1-(1-z) t} \frac{t^{k-1}(1-t)}{\operatorname{B}(k,2)}\,\mathrm dt,\quad k\in\Bbb N
$$
which can be interpreted as an expected value w.r.t. the $\operatorname{Beta}(k,2)$ distribution, i.e. $\mathsf E[(1-(1-z) X)^{-1}]$ with $X\sim\operatorname{Beta}(k,2)$. By [Jensen's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_inequality) we then have
$$
F^2\left({1,k \atop k+2};1-z\right)\leq \mathsf E[(1-(1-z) X)^{-2}]=\int_0^1\frac{1}{(1-(1-z) t)^2} \frac{t^{k-1}(1-t)}{\operatorname{B}(k,2)}\,\mathrm dt.
$$
Now note for $z>0$ and $t\in[0,1]$ that
$$
\min\{1,z^{-2}\}\leq\frac{1}{(1-(1-z) t)^2}\leq\max\{1,z^{-2}\}.
$$
Consequently,
$$
F^2\left({1,k \atop k+2};1-z\right)\leq\max\{1,z^{-2}\}
$$
and
$$
\tag{1}
I(z,s)\leq1+\max\{1,z^{-2}\}\left(\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(2-s)_k}{(k+1)^2k!}-1\right).
$$
By the properties of the Pochhammer symbol we now write $k+1=(2)_k/(1)_k$. Substituting this result into our inequality for $I$ gives
$$
I(z,s)\leq1+\max\{1,z^{-2}\}\left(\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(1)_k(1)_k(2-s)_k}{(2)_k(2)_kk!}-1\right),
$$
which according to [DLMF $\S 16.2(\mathrm{iii})$](http://dlmf.nist.gov/16.2.iii) is absolutely convergent if $\Re s>0$. Furthermore, if we evaluate the series we can obtain an explicit expression for the upper bound on $I$. Upon inspection of $(1)$ we see that
$$
I(z,s)\leq1+\max\{1,z^{-2}\}\left(I(1,s)-1\right).
$$

> Hence, for $z>0$ and $s\in\Bbb C:\Re s>0$:
> $$
> I(z,s)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(2-s)_k}{k!}\frac{F^2(1,k;k+2;1-z)}{(k+1)^2}
> $$
> and
> $$
> I(z,s)\leq1+\max\{1,z^{-2}\}\left(\frac{H_{s-1}}{s-1}-1\right).
> $$

Answer (score 1):

Maybe helpful, I don't really know, sometimes a different perspective sparks something. If you center the integration with the changes of variable
$x = (1 + u)/2$, $y = (1 + v)/2$ the integral becomes

\begin{equation}
z^{s - 2}\int_{-1}^{1}\int_{-1}^{1}
\left( \frac{u  v z - 2uv + uz + vz + z + 2}{(uz -u + z +1)(vz - v + z + 1)}\right)^{s-2}\,du\;dv.
\end{equation}
For a given $z$ the denominator vanishes when either
$u$ or $v$ equal $(1 + z)/(1 - z)$.

Interesting stuff!

**Added fun fact**

If computer algebra systems are to be trusted we have
\begin{equation}
I(z, 3) = 
{\left(z^{2} + z \log z - 3 \, z + 2\right)} {\left(z - \log z - 1\right)} z
{\left(z - 1\right)}^{-4}.
\end{equation}
I haven't checked if that matches with what we've seen so far, but for $z$ near $1$ this looks like $\frac{3}{4} + \frac{1}{6}(z - 1) - \frac{1}{9}(z - 1)^2 + \cdots$.

As you work your way higher there seems to be a pattern of the form
\begin{equation}
I(z, n) = (1 - z)^{-2n + 2}z \left( A_n^{(2n-1)}(z) + B_n^{(2n-3)}(z)\log^2 z + C_n^{(2n-3)}(z)\log z \right)
\end{equation}
where $A_m^{(k)}(z)$, $B_m^{(k)}(z)$, and $C_m^{(k)}(z)$ are polynomials of degree $k$ in $z$. Would be fun to see if a three-term recurrence relation for them is hiding somewhere.

Comment: From the point of view of the series representation of $I(z,s)$ in terms of hypergeometric functions, this  is related to the fact that $F(1,k,k+2,1-z)$ has a similar form in terms of a rational function over $z$ and $\log(z)$, at least for small $k$ -- maybe that can be established with an integral relationship?

Comment: I believe you can show that $F(1,k,k+2,x)/(k(k+1)) = \log(1-x)/x^{k+1} - \log(1-x)/x^k + 1/x^k - \sum_{n=1}^{k-1} z^{-n}/((k-n)(k-n+1))$. To derive this, note that $\int_0^1 t^{k-1}/(1-zt)\,dt = -\log(1-z)/z^k - 1/z^k \sum_{n=1}^{k-1} z^n/n$.